# Unity Tile with composed sprite

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a tile subclass for Unity's tilemap that would work similar to the RPG maker's [autotile system](http://blog.rpgmakerweb.com/tutorials/anatomy-of-an-autotile/). Basic idea is that you provide your tile set in texture in the format below and it will join adjacent tiles of same type.

[image]

From this texture all the required tile layouts should be generated by matching 4 quarter squares together to create full tile. For example if I wanted to create an "L" shaped tile I would just reference 4 rects of quarters 16, 3, 20, 21.

Is there a way I can create a single sprite that will reference that single template texture with multiple rects to form whole tile? Main choke point here is that the [TileData](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Tilemaps.TileData.html) takes only one sprite component.

Can I maybe somehow split mesh of this sprite into 4 squares and set the uv's to reference correct quarters in texture?

Comment: Just in case you didn't know this, Unity already has some tilemap extensions of their own which perform this kind of dynamic tile placement depending on neighbors. Google for their github page.

Comment: Yes I know there are many assets on the asset store that do autotiling but most of the time they aren't, or if they aren't that great. Also I would like to implement it myself and not use any external dependencies. If you know of some open source, autotiling package for unity, I would be happy if you could link it here. I wasn't able to find anything relevant.

Comment: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/2d-extras is the official package. Check youtube for one of Brackey's videos about tilemaps (i.e. search for "brackeys tilemaps") to see if it's really what you need. The github package is presented at the end.

Comment: @B.M. Thanks for the link. That package is doing exactly what I want to avoid doing and what the point of my question is, and that is creating all the the 47 tile combinations by hand and then assigning them manually.